# iframe in html CODE not able to load website

Tags: html, iframe

i am trying to load `www.google.com` in an iframe. But i am not getting required results.

Please help me to figure out the error.

here is the jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/vj04bk4d/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly protected and famous sites have already protected it from grabbing their page inside an iframe. Some others are not, e.g. w3schools.com. you'll see the page appears inside the iframe. That's why it is impossible to do that on protected site. Some say that this is against privacy and policy.

This is frequently done by PTC site.

Please check here for further information:
[jQuery/JavaScript: accessing contents of an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe)

Answer (score 1):

(My first stackoverflow answer, so bear with me.)

As I read in this other stackoverflow post:
[How do I load a URL specified in a textbox in an iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19393756/how-do-i-load-a-url-specified-in-a-textbox-in-an-iframe)

the problem is not in the code, but in the fact that "some sites refuse to load the page inside an iframe (example: http://google.com)"

I have a similar tool done here:
http://www.carljohansson.net/tools/a-simple-responsive-viewer.php
where I load the url from an input[type=text] to be shown inside an iframe to test the responsiveness of a website. While testing your issue I saw that google wouldn't load either on my page.

Cheers!